# Pass parameters to report Devexpress

Tags: winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

Please tell me. Created 2 classes (Data Model)

```
public class User 
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Office { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public float Mobile { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public int idArm { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class arm
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string Detalis { get; set; }
}
```

I installed 2 GridControlls on the form
And through DataSet showed data

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionSIPiT"].ConnectionString;

        string command = "SELECT * FROM Users";

        string command2 = "SELECT * FROM arm";

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command2, sqlConnection);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(command, sqlConnection);

        DataSet dataset1 = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(dataset1, "arm");
        adapter1.Fill(dataset1, "Users");

        DataColumn keyColumn = dataset1.Tables[0].Columns[0];
        DataColumn foreignKeyColumn = dataset1.Tables[1].Columns[9];
        dataset1.Relations.Add("armUsers", keyColumn, foreignKeyColumn);

        armBindingSource.DataSource = dataset1;
        armBindingSource.DataMember = "arm";

        userBindingSource.DataSource = armBindingSource;
        userBindingSource.DataMember = "armUsers";
        gridControl1.DataSource = userBindingSource;
        gridControl2.DataSource = armBindingSource;
```

How do I select a row in the main table GridControll. Send report data. Or pass the id of the main table to build the report? Can anyone come across such a task?

Comment: Are you saying that the user is selecting a Row in the Devexpress GridView, and when they do that you want to pass that Id as a parameter to show a Report? Is the Report on the same page or is it on a separate page? If so attach some code from the gridview itself so I can help answer your question

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the Modifiers property for the report parameter is set to Public or Internal
2. Use the GridView.GetRowCellValue method to get the ID column value of the focused record

The following assumes that you have a report called MyReport and it has a parameter called MyParameter.

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["UserID"]));
var rpt = new MyNewReport();
rpt.MyParameter.Value = id; //Make sure the MyParameter's Modifiers property is set to Public or Internal.
```